# Regex to match only if found 10 or more Social Security Numbers

Tags: regex

I'm looking to have a RegEx matching only if found 10 or more matches of Social Security Numbers (SSN). The SSN regex I am using is currently `(\b\d{9}\b)`. But, I want a RegEx to match only if `(\b\d{9}\b)` matches 10 or more times.

How do I solve this problem?

I was expecting `(\b\d{9}\b){10,}` to work, but it does not.

Comment: Should the same SSN occur at least 10 times, or just a SSN 10 times?

Comment: a SSN 10 times.

Comment: If it is supported, you could use a positive lookahead. What is the tool / language?

Answer (score 0):

you might need to calculate the count using applocation logic, use the regex for the ssn but count the number of groups in code

Comment: Thanks, that is what I have to resort to worst case. Seems like no one has any other solution?